# AssertJ SoftAssertions: how to execute custom code after an AssertionError is collected?

Tags: java, testng, assertion, allure, assertj

**Issue**: I want to change TestNG assertions to AssertJ and SoftAssertions from AssertJ, but I do not know what exactly I need to override from SoftAssertions to execute custom code after an `AssertionError` is collected. Specifically, I would like to get screenshots for each collected error. I use Selenium for Automation and need to add screenshots for reporting.
I tried to override each `fail` method from `AbstractSoftAssertions` but it did not help.

**Actual**: I got screenshots only in the `@After` method.

**Expected**: I need to get screenshots for each soft assertion error.

The current setup is with Java, TestNG, Selenium, and Allure report.

Comment: What do you mean by screenshot?  Could you give an example of what you are trying to convert?

Comment: @StefanoCordio  I do selenium automation and when use SoftAssertions I need for each soft assert, if it is fail, to make screenshot and see it in report. I have method for report and it is working fine, but not with SoftAssertions from AssertJ. And I am trying to add screenshot method somewhere in SoftAssertins!

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar enough with Selenium. Would you have the chance to share a reproducible example?

Comment: @StefanoCordio Let me tell you an example without selenium. For example: When I use SoftAssertions, during error recorded I need to print smth on a console.(at the moment of error). But in my case, I will use the method to make screenshot. I just need to figure out what method to override and how to be able to do above. If need more examples or details, please let me know! And thank you for trying to help.

Comment: thanks, got it now. I posted the options as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options:

- Call [`setAfterAssertionErrorCollected`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/DefaultAssertionErrorCollector.html#setAfterAssertionErrorCollected(org.assertj.core.api.AfterAssertionErrorCollected)) on your `SoftAssertions` instance, providing your own [`AfterAssertionErrorCollected`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AfterAssertionErrorCollected.html) implementation (can be a lambda).
- Extend `AbstractSoftAssertions` and overrride [`onAssertionErrorCollected​`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AfterAssertionErrorCollected.html#onAssertionErrorCollected(java.lang.AssertionError)).

Both ways allow you to provide your own logic to be executed with each assertion error.

You can find examples about both solutions in the [AssertJ documentation](https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-soft-assertions-collect-listener).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Thats what I am looking for and it is working as expected. Wish you all the best!=)